# No se ejecuta correctamente la sentencia de MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli

Mi problema es sencillo, tengo la siguiente sentencia en MySQL junto con codigo de PHP pero por alguna razon no se ejecuta, no me actualiza los datos correctamente o mas bien diria que no lo hace asi que quisiera saber que es lo que esta mal, ya revise mis variables y estan bien declaradas y me devuelven los datos correctos asi que el problema a mi parecer es aqui.

```
UPDATE forma (nombre, email, mensaje) VALUES ('$nombre', '$email', '$mensaje') WHERE id = $id
```

Comment: ¿Qué trae $id? Imprime antes de la actualización qué tiene dicha variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿de donde obtienes el dato id?
intenta hacer un echo de las variables
$nombre, $email, $mensaje y $id para estar seguro de que se envian los datos correctamente

puede ser un error de escritura, la variable id debes colocarla dentro de comillas

```
<?php 

UPDATE forma (nombre, email, mensaje) VALUES ('$nombre', '$email', '$mensaje') WHERE id = ".$id."

?>
```

Comment: No Juan, si la columna  `id` es numérica su sentencia es correcta así: `WHERE id = $id`
. En cambio puede haber otros errores en la consulta, en los datos, o puede que la actualización provoque duplicados y por eso no se realiza. Se podría verificar fácilmente comprobando por código el estado de la consulta e imprimiendo un mensaje adecuado.

Comment: gracias por la correxion @A.Cedano